# Laravel query builder: error in mysql where clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Here is my join query

```
$data['userslist'] = DB::table('users')
            ->select('users.*','user_roles.role_name')
            ->join('user_roles','users.user_type=user_roles.role_id')
            ->where('users.user_type','!=',1)
            ->get();
```

But i will get the following error in where clause

> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near '`` where `users`.`user_type` != ?' at
>   line 1 (SQL: select `users`.*, `user_roles`.`role_name` from `users`
>   inner join `user_roles` on `users`.`user_type=user_roles`.`role_id` ``
>   where `users`.`user_type` != 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to fetch users.user_type where value in not equal to 1. For this, you need to use '<>' in where clause

Now your query is as follow :

```
$data['userslist'] = DB::table('users')
        ->select('users.*','user_roles.role_name')
        ->join('user_roles', 'users.user_type', '=', 'user_roles.role_id')
        ->where('users.user_type','<>',1)
        ->get();
```

I hope you will get your solution.